# Mostly gray with two dark gray wheels

Tags: set-identification

Mostly gray with two dark gray wheels.
What set would they go to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Half cylinder 3 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87926) plus [Viking wagon wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55817) means [75292-1 The Razor Crest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75292-1).